# Smooth overflow:hidden

Tags: css, overflow, opacity

[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y049jbm8/) should explain my problem.
 I have a container with overflow:hidden. I want the content which is cut of, to be cut of "smoothly".
 The font should slowly become more transparent before it is cut off. I have found a solution, which you can see in my fiddle.

I would like to know if there is a more elegant solution compared to my solution. Right now there are 5 different transparency levels but i want to work with at least 10 different levels. Therefore it would get very messy. Thanks for your help!

Short HTML/CSS-Sample, which shows how much code is needed for this little effect:

HTML

```
<div id="transparencydiv">
    <div id="transparency1" class="transparencys"></div>
    <div id="transparency2" class="transparencys"></div>
    <div id="transparency3" class="transparencys"></div>
    <div id="transparency4" class="transparencys"></div>
    <div id="transparency5" class="transparencys"></div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
    #transparencydiv{
        position:absolute;
        top:45%;
        height:10%; width:100%;
    }
    .transparencys{
        float:right;
        height:100%;width:2ex;
        background-color:black;
        z-index:5;

    }
    #transparency1{opacity:0.9;margin-right:2%;}
    #transparency2{opacity:0.7;}
    #transparency3{opacity:0.5;}
    #transparency4{opacity:0.3;}
    #transparency5{opacity:0.1;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/y049jbm8/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `linear-gradient`:

```
#scrollmenu:after {
    content:" ";
    width:15%;
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    height:100%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255,255,255,0), black);
}
```

Check the **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y049jbm8/1/)**

---

#### Note :::

This will work on the latest Chrome, to keep compatibility use the necessary prefixes. You can check here for more info http://css-tricks.com/css3-gradients/

Comment: I don't get why this reply was marked as the solution, since with this approach, the right arrow would also get affected by the gradient.

Comment: @Marventus this answer provide a guide to the OP on how to acomplish that with linear-gradient .... this doesn't affect the arrows, the right arrow is positioned with absolute too and has more z-index so it¿s over the gradient of ::after element ... you post an answer with exact the same resource ... linear-gradient

Comment: Yeah, you are right, but then arrows should be set to `z-index:3`, because, in order for this to work properly, since `#content` has a z-index value of 1, you would need to set `#scrollmenu:after` to `z-index: 2` at least for the `after` pseudo-element to be visible! Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Marventus/bgm63eeL/

Comment: ......@Marventus the z-index value on #content isn't working since the element has a static position on the OP fiddle... In your fiddle you change those properties of content and then the z-index works.... I don't get your point to spam comments on this answer this works well .... you answer after 17mins of mine and the OP find it usefull

Comment: I accepted it as a solution, since I will never just include code from someone else. It doesn´t matter if there is a little mistake. I just needed the information and this post contains everything I wanted to know.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of multiple divs, you can add a unique div over your text, with a gradient as background.

On this site, you will be able to configure the gradient you want to make.
http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is **way** too complicated! You can just use a CSS gradient instead:

### HTML:

```
<div id="scrollmenu">
    <div id="arrow1"></div>
    <div id="content">
        <p>THIS CONTENT WILL SCROLL! Theres will always be a different word cut of in the end. somecontentsomecontentsomecontentsomecontentsomecontentsomecontentsomecontentsomecontentsomecontentsomecontentsomecontentsomecontentsomecontentsomecontent somecontentsomecontentsomecontentsomecontentsomecontentsomecontentsomecontentsomecontentsomecontentsomecontentsomecontentsomecontentsomecontentsomecontent</p>
        <div id="transparencydiv"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="arrow2"></div>
</div>
```

```
body, html {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
* {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
#scrollmenu {
    position:absolute;
    top:45%;
    height:10%;
    width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
}
#arrow1, #arrow2 {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    height:100%;
    width:2%;
    z-index:2;
    background-color:red;
}
#arrow1 {
    left:0;
}
#arrow2 {
    right:0;
}
#content {
    height:100%;
    margin-left:2%;
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
}
#transparencydiv {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 80%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,rgba(0,0,0,0)), color-stop(80%,rgba(0,0,0,0)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,0,0,1)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 80%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 80%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 80%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to right,  rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 80%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#00000000', endColorstr='#000000',GradientType=1 );
    height:100%;
    left:0;
    max-height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
}
```

### Fiddle:

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Marventus/quj44dsg/) for reference.

Answer (score 0):

The basic gradient overlay is probably just the way to go. However, for the sake of science, I tried to answer your question literally and make a truly dynamic and *transparent* text overlay.

Basically, you can set a linear gradient background on the container element that fades to transparent (you can adjust these gradients to get the desired effect with a [CSS Gradient Generator](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/)). In my snippet below, I put the text over an image so you can see that it's the text that is transparent, not an overlay making it look like it fades out.

```css
body { background: url('http://i.imgur.com/I5G6HaZ.jpg'); }

.container { 
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, white, transparent); 
  width: 50%;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

p {
  width: 20em;
  
  font-size: 24px;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper porta. Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Curabitur sodales ligula in libero.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I actually came back because my problem is way more complicated than I thought. The font, which has to be transparent, is on a transparent background. Therefore I can´t use a linearGradient overlay. Your option would work, but the color of the font will change aswell. One time it will be black, the other time it will be white. As a result I can´t use your solution. Do you have any other ideas to solve this problem?